# add to Cart via AJAX doesn't work

Tags: product, magento-1.9, cart, category, ajax

I use an AJAX way to add **some** products to the Cart. I have 3 stores.

My JS side is:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://example.com/donate_ajax/ajax/',
    data: $('#donationAddToCart').serializeFormJSON(),
    type: 'post',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(e){
       console.log(e);
    },
    error: function(){
       console.log('Error!');
    }
});
```

My PHP side:

```
    include_once 'Mage/Checkout/controllers/CartController.php';

    class AD_Donations_AjaxController extends Mage_Checkout_CartController
    {
        public function _initProductById( $productId )
        {
            if ( $productId ) {
                $product = Mage::getModel( 'catalog/product' )
                    ->setStoreId( Mage::app()->getStore()->getId() )
                    ->load( intval( $productId ) );
                if ( $product->getId() ) {
                    return $product;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }

        public function indexAction()
        {
            if ( $this->getRequest()->isXmlHttpRequest() ) {
                $params = $this->getRequest()->getParams();

                Mage::app()->setCurrentStore( intval( $params['store_id'] ) );

                $cart     = $this->_getCart();
                $response = array();
                try {
                    foreach ( $params['products'] as $key => $val ) {
                        if ( empty( $val ) ) continue;

                        $product = $this->_initProductById( $key );

                        if ( ! $product ) {
                            $response['products'][ $key ]['status']  = 'ERROR';
                            $response['products'][ $key ]['message'] = $this->__( 'Unable to find Product ID' );
                            continue;
                        }

                        $cart->addProduct( $product, array(
                            'qty' => $val
                        ) );

                        $cart->getQuote()->setTotalsCollectedFlag(false);

                        $cart->save();

                        $this->_getSession()->setCartWasUpdated( TRUE );

                        /**
                         * @todo remove wishlist observer processAddToCart
                         */
                        Mage::dispatchEvent( 'checkout_cart_add_product_complete',
                            array( 'product'  => $product,
                                   'request'  => $this->getRequest(),
                                   'response' => $this->getResponse()
                            )
                        );

                        if ( ! $this->_getSession()->getNoCartRedirect( true ) && !$cart->getQuote()->getHasError() ) {
                            $response['products'][ $key ]['status']  = 'SUCCESS';
                            $response['products'][ $key ]['message'] = $this->__( '%s was added to your shopping cart.', Mage::helper( 'core' )->htmlEscape( $product->getName() ) );
                            Mage::log( $this->__( '%s was added to your shopping cart.', Mage::helper( 'core' )->htmlEscape( $product->getName() ) ) );
                        } else {
                            $response['products'][ $key ]['status']  = 'ERROR';
                            $response['products'][ $key ]['message'] = $this->__( 'Cannot add %s to shopping cart.', Mage::helper( 'core' )->htmlEscape( $product->getName() ) );
                            Mage::log( $this->__( 'Cannot add %s to shopping cart.', Mage::helper( 'core' )->htmlEscape( $product->getName() ) ) );
                        }
                    }
                } catch ( Mage_Core_Exception $e ) {
                    $msg = "";
                    if ( $this->_getSession()->getUseNotice( TRUE ) ) {
                        $msg = $e->getMessage();
                    } else {
                        $messages = array_unique( explode( "\n", $e->getMessage() ) );
                        foreach ( $messages as $message ) {
                            $msg .= $message . '<br/>';
                        }
                    }

                    $response['status']  = 'ERROR';
                    $response['message'] = $msg;
                } catch ( Exception $e ) {
                    $response['status']  = 'ERROR';
                    $response['message'] = $this->__( 'Cannot add the item to shopping cart.' );
                    Mage::logException( $e );
                }


                foreach ($cart->getQuote()->getAllItems() as $item) {
                    $response['cart'][] = array(
                        'name' => $item->getProduct()->getName(),
                        'price' => $item->getProduct()->getPrice(),
                        'qty' => $item->getProduct()->getQty(),
                        '_data' => $item->getProduct()->getData()
                    );
                }

                $this->getResponse()->setBody( Mage::helper( 'core' )->jsonEncode( $response ) );

                return;
            } else {
                $this->_redirect( '/' );
            }
        }

    }
```

What can I see as JSON result:

[image: JSON Result]

But the problem is, that when I refresh the page in the browser, no added products using this way are shown!

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Check cookie path of your stores

Answer (score 0):

OK, I found the matter.  It's because I haven't set **form_key** GET/POST variable which is mandatory.

So it works for me now.